# WPFExtendedToolkit PropertyGrid Standard Values

Tags: propertygrid, icustomtypedescriptor, wpf-extended-toolkit

I'm trying to display `XmlElement`'s attributes in Xceed PropertyGrid. For that purpose I defined custom wrapper class. It wraps XmlElement, iterates over XmlAttributes and creates custom PropertyDescriptor for each XmlAttribute. All "virtual" properties' type is `String`. All works fine. 
Now I want to have drop-down list of possible attribute values for every attribute that has restricted set of values. In Xceed's PropertyGrid, there is `ItemsSourceAttribute` for that. But it has to be applied as follows:

```
ItemsSourceAttribute(typeof(MyCustomItemsSource))
```

And here is the problem - I can not provide proper argument for `MyCustomItemsSource` constructor. What can I do about this?

It seems that there is another possibility - to define a TypeConverter, override GetStandardValues, and supply this converter to "virtual" property. But PropertyGrid just ignores this attribute.

How this simple task can be done with Xceed PropertyGrid?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I implemented custom editor

```
public class AttributeValuesEditor: Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Editors.ComboBoxEditor
{
    protected override IEnumerable CreateItemsSource(PropertyItem propertyItem)
    {
        var property = propertyItem.PropertyDescriptor as XmlAttributePropertyDescriptor;
        Debug.Assert(property!=null);
        return property.GetCompletionValues();
    }
}
```

Here, the context is passed into method in the form of `PropertyItem`. Now it is possible to differentiate between different attributes and return appropriate items.